# Debian Lenny Adafruit_BBIO failure to install

Tags: debian, python, pip, gpio

I have Debian Lenny installed on a Beagle bone Black Rev B. I have been following the outlined steps provided on this web page: https://learn.adafruit.com/character-lcd-with-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/usage . I'm able to get to the installation point, and to the command "  sudo pip install Adafruit_BBIO". However, after running this command it eventually errors out stating:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gkkzPQ/Adafruit-BBIO/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9dhrYO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gkkzPQ/Adafruit-BBIO
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm unable to get past this, and i'm hoping that someone here can point me to the correct direction in getting this resolved.
I did perform a "Test" of sorts by attempting to run one of the examples. After modifying it to match the BeagleBoards configuration for my 16x2 HD44780 LCD it returns this on running:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/examples$ python char_lcd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "char_lcd.py", line 6, in <module>
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 89, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 95, in Adafruit_CharLCD
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py", line 321, in get_platform_gpio
ImportError: No module named Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO
```

Contents of /root/.pip/pip.log are here http://pastebin.com/atsCp6xu

Comment: care  to add the contents of /root/.pip/pip.log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/atsCp6xu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly shown on line 202 of the log.

```
source/common.c:385:5: error: format not a string literal and no format argumes [-Werror=format-security]

     fprintf(file, name);

     ^
```

The compiler has spotted an unsafe construct, namely passing a string to printf without a format. There are two solutions to this, either tell the compiler that this is not a problem, or fix it.

```
fprintf(file, "%s", name);
```

there are other warnings that could also use attention, and there may be other errors that will show up after this one is resolved.